# cloning git hub repository shows fatal error on proxy connection

Tags: git, proxy

while cloning a repository from github shows fatal error `errno=invalid arguments`. I use a proxy connection

I already changed the git config file to the proxy port and ip.

Still the problem persists.[image: image attached belowe]

[2nd imge shows the git config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTin4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Response based on config screenshot

Okay - looking at your global git config, there are several weird things that could be causing the problem:

> ```
> [http]
>     sslVerify = false
>     proxy = https://0004:password@192.168.23.32:3128
> [https]
> [https]
>     proxy = http://192.168.23.32:3128
> ```

1. There is a duplicate [https] header - remove it (the first one with nothing under it)!
2. I'm not sure exactly what the sslVerify statement does - I've seen this before and it might be okay - but what's weird is that it only shows up on your [http] and not on your [https] section. If the other fixes don't work, I'd research exactly what this does and whether this setting is right for your proxy.  Also - whether you need it in both sections or not
3. In the [http] section the proxy value starts with `https://`, but from what I understand this should *always* be just `http://`.  Remove the 's'.
4. The [http] section has the `user:password@` option, but the [https] section doesn't.  The way I understand this, they should be the same.  I'd try both without this at all, and both with it.
5. Assuming you need the `user:password@` for the proxy, is your username really "0004", and is your password just "password"?  I believe this is the literal text passed to the proxy, I'd double check that.
6. I'll point out that 192.168.x.x must be an internal address, and it might be the network you or your company uses locally, so that could be completely correct for the proxy, but you might want to double check in your web browser proxy settings (the procedure will vary to get to it based on OS and/or browser used).

I'm not sure which of these is the culprit.  Let us know if you figure it out!

---

### Original Response - How to Troubleshoot a Proxy Issue

I can't help you without more information, but here are several things you can do to get that information and dig into this further. You might even find the solution to your problem in the process.

I recommend adding the output of the following to the end of your answer:

1. Post the commands you used to setup the proxy.

   Hopefully the proxy setting commands you used were something like:

   > ```
   > > git config --global http.proxy http://[username:password@]<proxy URL>:<proxy port>
   > > git config --global https.proxy http://[username:password@]<proxy URL>:<proxy port>
   > ```
2. Get the current proxy that your git repo is trying to use, use `git config --get-urlmatch http.proxy http://github.com` from your repo directory. If it is not what you expect, then you set up the proxy wrong.
3. Use `git config --global -e`.  This will open up the global git config file for editing. Find the sections [http] and [https] and cut and paste them into your question (you might not have both) along with the `key=value` pairs in each section.  This should be something like:

   > ```
   > [http]
   >     proxy = http://myproxy.myorg:8080
   > [https]
   >     proxy = http://myproxy.myord:8080
   > ```
4. Use `git config -e` while in the repo directory to bring up the local repo config file - does it have an [http] or [https] section in it?  If so, post that too.

Comment: the commands which i used to change my proxy are exactly the same as u mentioned in point no. 1.

Comment: when running the command in your point 2. the proxy is shown to be set correct as desired.

Comment: regarding point no 3 i hvae updated my question with the screenshot of the git config file

Comment: regarding your 4th point the repository has not been cloned yet , so i could not run the command in a repo in my system @LightCC

Comment: I edited the answer to add the **`Updated Response`** section at the start with some strange things in that global Git config file.  Please note that you can directly edit those [http] and [https] sections and save and retry to your heart's content.

Comment: can u please tel how to edit those http and https sections....also the command     git config --global -e doesent seem to be wrking for me now. previously it did as i shared with u the screenshot. the problem is still not resolved @LightCC

Comment: i edited the sections ...still unable to clone. I am not even able to ping to google.com even though i set proxy for cmd

Comment: Well - I'm running thin on possibilities.  What do you mean that you set up proxy for cmd?  You mean like http_proxy and no_proxy type of environment variables?  You may need to remove any environment variables you added and even might need to uninstall and reinstall Git completely.  If you can't ping from the cmd-line, then it's outside of Git's control - there is something else going on.  Are you sure the proxy is working with that IP:port and username:password for other programs?

Comment: @shubhamkumardubey Did you get `git config --global -e` to work, or did you just find the file and directly edit? I mainly use that command because it will open it no matter what platform you are on, but if you can find the global config file, you can just open and edit it. It would be good to save a backup copy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:
Direct to the git path using commandline.check the configuration

```
git config --list
```

then add the proxy settings:

```
git config --global user.name "saik#########"      
git config --global user.email "saikumarputta01@gmail.com"
```

Check your Proxy settings:

```
git config --list
```

or

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email    @This shows your credentials@
```

Go the path of your project

```
git init  
touch initial  
git add initial  
git remote add origin "https://github.com/saikumarputta/TodoApi.git"  
git push -u origin
```

To remove all the proxy settings in the configuration

```
git config --global --unset proxy settings;
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
```

To remove the remote server of the github:

```
git remote remove origin.
```